# Client Server Security Architecture

Tags: security, architecture, client-server, cloud

I would like go get my head around how is best to set up a client server architecture where security is of up most importance.

So far I have the following which I hope someone can tell me if its good enough, or it there are other things I need to think about. Or if I have the wrong end of the stick and need to rethink things.

- Use SSL certificate on the server to ensure the traffic is secure.
- Have a firewall set up between the server and client.
- Have a separate sql db server.
- Have a separate db for my security model data.
- Store my passwords in the database using a secure hashing function such as PBKDF2.
- Passwords generated using a salt which is stored in a different db to the passwords.
- Use cloud based infrastructure such as AWS to ensure that the system is easily scalable.

I would really like to know is there any other steps or layers I need to make this secure.  Is storing everything in the cloud wise, or should I have some physical servers as well?

I have tried searching for some diagrams which could help me understand but I cannot find any which seem to be appropriate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardening your architecture can be a challenging task and sharding your services across multiple servers and over-engineering your architecture for semblance security could prove to be your largest security weakness.

However, a number of questions arise when you come to design your IT infrastructure which can't be answered in a single SO answer (will try to find some good white papers and append them).

There are a few things I would advise which is somewhat opinionated backed up with my own thought around it.

---

### Your Questions

> I would really like to know is there any other steps or layers I need to make this secure. Is storing everything in the cloud wise, or should I have some physical servers as well?

Settle for the cloud. You do not need to store things on physical servers anymore unless you have current business processes running core business functions that are already working on local physical machines.

Running physical servers increases your system administration requirements for things such as HDD encryption and physical security requirements which can be misconfigured or completely ignored.

> Use SSL certificate on the server to ensure the traffic is secure.

This is normally a no-brainer and I would go with a straight, "Yes"; however you must take into consideration the context. If you are running something such as a blog site or documentation-related website that does not transfer any sensitive information at any point in time through `HTTP` then why use `HTTPS`? HTTPS has it's own overhead, it's minimal, but it's still there. That said, **if in doubt, enable HTTPS**.

> Have a firewall set up between the server and client.

That is suggested, you may also want to opt for a service such as [CloudFlare WAF](https://www.cloudflare.com/waf/), I haven't personally used it though.

> Have a separate sql db server.

Yes, however not necessarily for security purposes. Database servers and Web Application servers have different hardware requirements and optimizing both simultaneously is not very feasible. Additionally, having them on separate boxes increases your scalability quite a bit which will be beneficial in the long run.

From a security perspective; it's mostly another illusion of, "If I have two boxes and the attacker compromises one [Web Application Server], he won't have access to the Database server".

At foresight, this might seem to be the case but is rarely so. Compromising the Web Application server is still almost a guaranteed Game Over. I will not go into much detail into this (unless you specifically ask me to) however it's still a good idea to keep both services separate from eachother in their own boxes.

> Have a separate db for my security model data.

I'm not sure I understood this, what security model are you referring to exactly? Care to share a diagram or two (maybe an ERD) so we can get a better understanding.

> Store my passwords in the database using a secure hashing function such as PBKDF2.

Obvious yes; what I am about to say however is controversial and may be flagged by some people (it's a bit of a hot debate)—I recommend using `BCrypt` instead of `PKBDF2` due to BCrypt being slower to compute (resulting in slower to crack).

See - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage

> Passwords generated using a salt which is stored in a different db to the passwords.

If you use BCrypt I would not see why this is required (I may be wrong). I go into more detail regarding the whole username and password hashing into more detail in the following StackOverflow answer which I would recommend you to read - [Back end password encryption vs hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892173/back-end-password-encryption-vs-hashing/36898588#36898588)

> Use cloud based infrastructure such as AWS to ensure that the system is easily scalable.

This purely depends on your goals, budget and requirements. I would personally go for AWS, however you should read some more on alternative platforms such as Google Cloud Platform before making your decision.

### Last Remarks

All of the things you mentioned are important and it's good that you are even considering them (most people just ignore such questions or go with the most popular answer) however there are a few additional things I want to point:

- **Internal Services** - Make sure that no unrequired services and processes are running on server especially in productions. These services will normally be running old versions of their software (since you won't be administering them) that could be used as an entrypoint for your server to be compromised.
- **Code Securely** - This may seem like another no-brainer yet it is still overlooked or not done properly. Investigate what frameworks you are using, how they handle security and whether they are actually secure. As a developer (and not a pen-tester) you should *at least* use an automated web application scanner (such as [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/)) to run security tests after each build that is pushed to make sure you haven't introduced any obvious, critical vulnerabilities.
- **Limit Exposure** - Goes somewhat hand-in-hand with my first point. Make sure that services are only exposed to other services that depend on them and nothing else. As a rule of thumb, keep everything entirely closed and open up gradually when strictly required.

My last few points may come off as broad. The intention is to keep a certain philosophy when developing your software and infrastructure rather than a permanent rule to tick on a check-box.

There are probably a few things I have missed out. I will update the answer accordingly over time if need be. :-)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.. Your comments are really appreciated in my understanding. One other question, should I have a separate firewall between my application server and database box?

Comment: ... Also is there any particular frameworks you would use to ensure security?

Comment: Nothing at all. To answer your questions -- you should also have internal firewalls in place along with your Web Application Firewalls (WAFs) to limit what ports (amongst other rules) you want to enforce within your network. WAFs/Firewalls aren't something I'm particularly well versed in unfortunately so I would not be able to help you very much regarding that :-(

Comment: Regarding frameworks, that's normally language-bound so I can't quite answer. An example would be to use `ItsDangerous` and `Flask-Security`  along with `Flask` but that's very broad. Just take a step back, evaluate your technology stack and ask around (even the developers) regarding security. You notice how secure a framework tends to be depending on how the development team responds to security-related questions.