# Decrypt Encrypted Password on MongoDB and then compare it with the password which user has entered

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, encryption

I am new to ExpressJS. I have made an API which inserts user's email and encrypted password into MongoDB. Now I want to decrypt the password which is stored on MongoDB and compare it with the password user has entered. I have no idea how to do that, so any help would be appreciated. Here is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Importing Model
const User = require('../models/model.js');


// Find User
router.post('/find' , (req , res) => {    // This is the method which checks the DB for user's email and password
    User.find({email : req.body.email , password : req.body.password})
        .then((users) => {
            if (users.length != 0) {
                res.json({result : true});
            }
            else {
                res.json({result : false});
            }
        })
});


//  Add User
router.post('/' , (req , res) => {
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password , 'secret key 123').toString();   // Encryption
const newUser = new User({
    email : req.body.email,
    password : ciphertext,
})

newUser.save().then((user) => res.json(user))
});


//  Exporting Router
module.exports = router;
```

This is the method provided by crypto-js for decryption :

```
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

I need to decrypt using this code in my POST (Find User) Route.

Comment: please don't do that. Instead of encrypting/decrypting passwords, store a hash of the password and compare hashes

Comment: @jps implemented hashing in my awnser instead of encription

Answer (score 0):

First things first,
Your find user route should be `GET` and not `POST`, POST is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

Quick overview about HTTP methods, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

To decrypt your data, `crypto-js` provides a decrypt method.
So check this code out

```js
// Encrypt
const password = "This is my password"

var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, 'secret key 123').toString();
 
// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(password === originalText) // returns true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi usually we don't want to be able to decrypt a users password but compare an hashed version with the given password that we hashed as well. This is because encription is less secure then hashing in an event of a data breach.

I use `bcrypt` to hash my passwords and check it against an other password.

```js
const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
  req.body.password, // the plane text password that we get from the client
  user.password,     // the hashed password from our database
)

if (!validPassword)  // return to the user that the password is invalid
  return res
    .status(status.BadRequest)
    .send('Invalid email or password')
```

To create the users hashed password:

```js
// generate a salt that will be added to the password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(
  item.password, // the plain text password we got from the user
  salt
)

// now we can save 'hash' (the hashed password) to our database with the users information
```

[Read more on the difference of hashing and encryption.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892173/back-end-password-encryption-vs-hashing)